# Can't I use an existing class inside a PHP constructor?

Tags: php, methods, constructor, mysqli

I'm somewhat new to OOP and trying to convert a lot of my existing code using classes. My first class is "Job", and my main script calls:

```
##
## New JOB Instance begins
##
$job = new Job();
$job->validate($job_status,$ber_order_number);
$job->sID($job->ExistingOrNew());
$job->parseJobInfo( $msg_blocks['Job Information']);
$job->parseLocationInfo( $msg_blocks['Location Address']);
$job->parseContactInfo( $msg_blocks['Contact Information']);
```

Inside my job.class.php, I'm trying to use a constructor to open the connection to and establish the link for my database, $_dblink is defined as private:

```
function __construct() {
    $_dblink = new mysqli( $this->_server, $this->_user, $this->_pass, "jobs" );        // connection to the jobs database
    if ( $_dblink->connect_error ) {
        die( 'Connect Error (' . $_dblink->connect_errno . ') ' . $_dblink->connect_error );
    }
}
```

As soon as I hit my "ExistingOrNew" method, I get **Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object**

```
function ExistingOrNew( ) {
    $q = "SELECT id FROM " . jJOBS . " WHERE order_number = '" . $this->order_number . "'";
    #
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this);
    echo "</pre>";
    #
    if ( $r = $this->_dblink->query( $q )) {
        while ( $row = $r->fetch_assoc( )) {
            $id = $row['id'];
        }
        $r->free( );
    }
    if ( empty ( $id )) {
        $id = $this->Create( );
    }
    return $id;
}
```

I don't understand why my private $_dblink variable is not carrying down to subsequent methods. What am I missing?

Comment: Use **`$this->_dblink`** to access `$_dblink`.

Answer (score 2):

You must make the link a class member, so you can use it later with the `$this->` operator.

```
function __construct() {
    $this=>_dblink = new mysqli( $this->_server, $this->_user, $this->_pass, "jobs" );        // connection to the jobs database
    if ( $this->_dblink->connect_error ) {
        die( 'Connect Error (' . $_dblink->connect_errno . ') ' . $_dblink->connect_error );
    }
}
```